# Alt Codes in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a good interface in batch and alt-codes do not work in batch. Is there a workaround?

I want to use alt codes in batch but it just return other plaintext characters.

Comment: "Batch" as in DOS `.bat` files? Or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by Alt codes? Non-ASCII characters entered via Alt+Numpad?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties of the console window and set a TrueType font, e.g. Consolas or Lucida Console instead of Raster Fonts.

Otherwise you're stuck with the OEM charset and it will convert everything that isn't in there into its closest equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Past this into a .cmd or .bat files and run it You'll see every code and they'll alt-code

In CMD / Batch some codes translate differently so you'll need to verify the code will work I did 1-254 on the Alt commands any more and they start to repeart
Here's the Code

```
echo off
:loop
cls
echo.  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
echo. 0 ? ? ? ? ? ? • ? ? ?
echo. 1 ? ? ? ? ¤ ? ? ? ? ¶
echo. 2 § ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
echo. 3 ?   ! " # $ %% & ' (
echo. 4 ) * + , - . / 0 1 2
echo. 5 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; -
echo. 6 ^= ^> ? @ A B C D E F
echo. 7 G H I J K L M N O P
echo. 8 Q R S T U V W X Y Z
echo. 9 [ ? \ ] _ ` a b c d
echo 10 e f g h i j k l m n
echo 11 o p q r s t u v w x
echo 12 y z ^{ ^| ^} ~ ^¦ Ç ü é
echo 13 â ä à å ç ê ë è ï î
echo 14 ì Ä Å É æ Æ ô ö ò û
echo 15 ù ÿ Ö Ü ¢ £ ¥ P ƒ á
echo 16 í ó ú ñ Ñ ª º ¿ ¬ ¬
echo 17 ½ ¼ ¡ « » ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦
echo 18 ¦ ¦ + + ¦ ¦ + + + +
echo 19 + + - - + - + ¦ ¦ +
echo 20 + - - ¦ - + - - - +
echo 21 + + + + + + + + ¦ _
echo 22 ¦ ¦ ¯ a ß G p S s µ
echo 23 t F T O d 8 f e n =
echo 24 ± = = ( ) ÷ ˜ ° · ·
echo 25 v n ² ¦  
Pause >nul
goto :loop
```

**Here's a Picture of the outcome**

[image]