# Windows Cmd: cannot get the input character properly

Tags: c, windows, cmd, codepages

I cannot get my input character value properly. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    char buf_in[32] = { 0 };
    printf("input: ");
    gets_s(buf_in, 32);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        printf("%02x ", buf_in[i]);
    getchar();
}
```

I input the character by `<alt-254>`, but the result is `74 00 00 ...`, not `fe 00 00 ...`.

Here is my local environment: `chcp 936`.

And I test in some different local environments (ANSI code page 936):
1. OEM code page 936   result : `74 00 00 ...`
2. OEM code page 65001 result : `00 00 00 ...` (weird)
3. OEM code page 1250  result : `3f 00 00 ...`
4. OEM code page 437   result : `5f 00 00 ...`

Comment: How about unsigned char instead of char. Here is an article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337217/difference-between-signed-unsigned-char

Comment: @user2443447 no, it doesn't work

Comment: Tried almost all input methods; the closest seem to be `std::wcin` or `wscanf` from [How to use Unicode in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3010739/3439404) thread…

Answer (score 0):

I think ALT-codes are not supported by windows console. Please look here:
[Alt Codes in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085377/alt-codes-in-batch)

You can try to put ALT-code (or any other data...) in file and then redirect input to Your program:

./prog.exe < input.txt

To be sure that you put proper value in file i suggest to use hex editor (like XVI32)

Does it work for other characters?

Comment: Nope. [ALT-codes **are supported** by windows console](http://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602). Maybe using [`wchar` instead of `char`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496203/char-vs-wchar-t) could help?